# How to update deployed bucket on compute engine instance?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have deployed spring boot application on google compute engine using this link (https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/kotlin-springboot-compute-engine#before_you_begin) from my local computer using the cloud SDK command line. I have created the google storage bucket and then followed the steps in the link to deploy the spring boot project. Deployment works fine. But now I have to deploy changes to my deployed project. How can that be achieved using command line without restarting the VM instance?

I have updated the google storage bucket which I provided in the --metadata BUCKET= while creating the instance.
Copied my new jar from the local location after building the project to the google cloud bucket. But after refreshing the URL in the browser can't see the new changes.

Comment: Please give more details of your issue & expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand in your description, you need to download the new version from the bucket to your VM, in the same directory where you created the instance-startup.sh as in [1], you can execute the command "gsutil cp gs://${BUCKET}/demo.jar ." this if you replaced the .jar file in the bucket, if the name changed you can change it in the previous command in order to make it match with the new version that you uploaded.

Then you can then stop the java process with the previous jar file, you may use "ps -aux | grep ${jarfilename}" and then "kill $PID", after this you can execute the new version with the command "java -jar $jarfile.jar" making it match with the new version of your jar file.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/kotlin-springboot-compute-engine#create_a_startup_script

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It helps